# Dependencies within the module dependencies?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

If `mainApp` has dependencies on module `app1`, `app2`, like `angular.module("mainApp", ['app1', 'app2'])`, this does not imply the dependencies between `app1` and `app2`, right? Or say, this does not mean that`app2` can use anything defined in `app1`, without anywhere defined `angular.module("app2", ['app1'])`?

Comment: All components will be available throughout the app regardless of which module they are declared in ... does that help?

Comment: @charlietfl You mean as long as the modules are injected and loaded, the those modules can access each other? No matter what the dependencies declared?

Comment: yes... exactly. factory registerd in app2, that module injected into app1, app1 injected into main. Can use that factory anywhere

Comment: @charlietfl Interesting! Follow-up question:  in this sense, what's the point of defining "dependencies"?

Comment: Ever used angular-ui-bootstrap? It has all sorts of modules in it with services and providers and templates in `$templatCache`, directives etc. Is simple to plug their main module into your main and use those components wherever you need them

Comment: @charlietfl Cool! Maybe try it someday. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) on Dependency Injections. It explains the way Angular utilizes this design pattern pretty well.